# Simple SQL query returning null value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I just started studying SQL queries.
I am practicing on this site: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins_try_sql.php

I want to find:

> "the name of the employee with the highest salary for every department".

My query is:

```
SELECT first_name, max(salary) FROM employees, departments 
WHERE departments.dept_id=employees.dept_id
GROUP BY employees.dept_id
```

And I get null value for `first_name` : 
[image: query result]
I understand that the problem is due to the `group by` expressions. But how can I solve this?

Tables:
[image: query result]

Comment: Do you have a first_name set in the employees table for all the records?

Comment: We need to see the structure of these two tables in order to help further.

Comment: Yes I have. You can check the tables data in the first link if you want. Or I can post them for you

Comment: Ok I post the two tables. Thanks

Comment: I posted the tables.

Comment: why is this tagged both mysql and sql-server?  which is it?

Comment: sorry. Updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternatively use `row_number()` like below, you don't need to join to departments table unless you need to show the name of the department:

```
Select e.*
from employees e
INNER JOIN
(
   SELECT e.id, e.dept_id. e.first_name, 
          rn=row_number() over (partition by e.dept_id order by e.salary desc)
   FROM employees e 
) x ON x.id = e.id
where x.rn = 1
```

**EDIT**

(Since OP does not want to use row_number() function amd it turned out the query will be used in mysql instead of sql server) -> Can you please try this:

```
select em.*
from employees em, (
    Select dept_id, max(salary) salary
    from employees e
    group by dept_id
) x on x.dept_id=em.dept_id and x.salary = em.salary
```

That should work but the online compiler does not accept join with a sub-query as far as I understand. Easiest solution I can think of, in this case:

```
select em.*
from employees em
where salary = (select max(salary) from employees em2 where em.dept_id = em2.dept_id)
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't written in the post: I only want to use SELECT, WHERE, JOIN , GROUP BY, HAVING... Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer. @l000000l

Comment: I tried this also, as a mysql query, but it does not work. I'm practicing on this site https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/joins_try_sql.php , i think i need simpler expressions to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT top 2 first_name,max(salary) FROM employees, departments
WHERE departments.dept_id=employees.dept_id

GROUP BY first_name
order by max(salary) desc
```

Comment: Can you provide more information instead of a code-only answer?

Comment: @chevybow first_name is selected but not included in the Group by clause so i added it in group by and ordered them by max salary.
I think somehow the online compiler  rather than showing the error it is showing null in the place of that.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT e.first_name, e.salary FROM employees as e
INNER JOIN departments as d ON d.dept_id=e.dept_id
WHERE e.salary IN (SELECT max(salary) FROM employees GROUP BY dept_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select first_name, b.dept_id, salary  from employees a,
(
SELECT employees.dept_id, max(salary) as salary FROM employees, departments 
WHERE departments.dept_id=employees.dept_id
GROUP BY employees.dept_id
 )b where a.salary = b.salary and a.dept_id= b.dept_id
```

Comment: Its the max salary for EVERY department ... This only returns the max salary

Comment: @zip what happens if different people in different departments have same amount of salary?